# Index out of bounds Exception but can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

Basically I have to take user input until they enter 0 and then find the max, number of negative numbers, and sum of positive numbers in the array. The problem is I have to use and array and cannot use ArrayList to call the other methods so I thought I would create an ArrayList and use the elements of that to create an array since there is an unspecified number of elements in the array. I keep getting this as errors and have tried everything I could think of. Please help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at Assignment9.assignment9(Assignment9.java:37)
    at Assignment9.assignment9(Assignment9.java:49)
    at Assignment9.assignment9(Assignment9.java:49)
    at Assignment9.assignment9(Assignment9.java:49)
    at Assignment9.main(Assignment9.java:17)
```

---

```
//Class Description: Takes user input and makes it into an array until 0 is entered.
// It then computes the maximum #, amount of negative #s and the sum of the positive #s.
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;;

public class Assignment9 {

//main method initializes variables then calls method assignment9
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> help = new ArrayList<Double>();
    assignment9(help, count);
}//end main

//adds user input to array until 0 is entered; it then calls other methods
public static void assignment9(ArrayList<Double> help, int count)
{
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double input;
    double max = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    input = scan.nextInt();

    if (input == 0)
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[help.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = help.get(i);
        }
        findMax(numbers, count, max);
        countNegative(numbers, count, negative);
        computeSumPositive(numbers, count, sum);
        System.out.println("The maximum numer is " + fmt.format(max));
        System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " + negative);
        System.out.println("The sum of positive numbers is " + fmt.format(sum));
        System.exit(0);
    }else{
            help.add(input);
            count++;
            assignment9(help, count);
    }//end if
}//end assignment9

//compares elements of array to find the max until count = -1
public static double findMax(double[] numbers, int count, double max)
{

    if (count == -1)
    {
        return max;
    }else if(numbers[count] > max){
        max = numbers[count];
        count--;
        findMax(numbers, count, max);
    }//end if
    return max;

}//end findMax

public static int countNegative(double[] numbers, int count, int negative)
{

    if(count == -1)
    {
        return negative;
    }else if(numbers[count] < 0){
        negative++;
        count--;
        countNegative(numbers, count, negative);
    }
    return negative;
}//end countNegative

public static double computeSumPositive(double[] numbers, int count, double sum)
{
     if(count == -1)
     {
         return sum;
     }else{
         sum = sum + numbers[count];
         count++;
         computeSumPositive(numbers, count, sum);
         return sum;
     }
}//end computeSumPositive
```

}//end class

Comment: The exception gives you a hint: *Index: 3, Size: 3*. Your code is trying to go to *someArray[3]* although it has only *[0,1,2]*. (Arrays are 0 based in Java)

Comment: I tried changing it to    double[]numbers = new double[count] and also tried leaving it and changing the parameters of the for loop to a bunch of different things but I keep getting errors such as IndexOutOfBoundsException 3. Can anyone help me with a quick fix?

Comment: Well now I just realized I think its the recursion that is screwed up but idk what is wrong

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are passing in the number `count` into `findMax` and it's throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while attempting to access the upper limit on this line:

```
} else if (numbers[count] > max) {
```

Remember arrays in Java are zero based. Also, as Java uses *pass by value* you need to assign the result to the output of `findMax`:

```
max = findMax(numbers, count - 1, 0);
```

---

Logically, `findMax` will always return the *last* number rather than the highest number. You need to return the temporary `max` from within the recursive method:

```
double findMax(double numbers[], int count, int index) {
   // This needs to be size - 1 because the array is 0-indexed.
   // This is our base case
   if (index == count - 1)
      return numbers[index];

   // Call the function recursively on less of the array
   double result = findMax(numbers, count, index + 1);

   // Return the max of (the first element we are examining, the max of the
   // rest of the array)
   if (numbers[index] > result)
      return numbers[index];
   else
      return result;
}
```

This version handles the `count` index upper limit internally:

```
max = findMax(numbers, count, 0);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, well I fixed all those errors and now my problem is it is printing 0 for the max and sums. I'm assuming its a problem with returning the answers and them printing them using the Assignment method. When you return a number, does only the main method have access to it? and if so that would mean I would have to call all the methods in my main method right?

Comment: You mean the `assignment9` method? Java is _pass-by-value_ so the `max` value so any changes in the value of `max` passed in won't be reflected in `max` in the method `assignment9`. i.e. use the returned value

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. Do you mean it is ok to use the retuned values in the assignment9 method and if so why is it printing 0? or do I have to use the main method to print?

Comment: It's ok to use `assignment9`